# Easiest way to copy/clone a mongoose document instance?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, instance, document

My approach would be to get the document instance, and create a new one from the instance fields. I am sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean by "copy/clone"? Are you going trying to create a duplicate document in the database? Or are you just trying to have two `var`s in your program that have duplicate data?

If you just do:

```
Model.findById(yourid).exec(
    function(err, doc) { 
        var x = doc; 
        Model.findById(yourid).exec(
            function(err, doc2) {
                var y = doc2;
                // right now, x.name and y.name are the same
                x.name = "name_x";
                y.name = "name_y";
                console.log(x.name); // prints "name_x"
                console.log(y.name); // prints "name_y"
            }); 
    });
```

In this case, `x` and `y` will be two "copies" of the same document within your program.

Alternatively, if you wanted to insert a new copy of the doc into the database (though with a different `_id` I assume), that would look like this:

```
Model.findById(yourid).exec(
    function(err, doc) {
        var d1 = doc;
        d1._id = /* set a new _id here */;
        d1.isNew = true;
        d1.save(callback);
    }
);
```

Or if you're doing this from the outset, aka you created some document `d1`, you can just call `save` twice without setting the `_id`:

```
var d1 = new Model({ name: "John Doe", age: 54 });
d1.save(callback);
d1.save(callback);
```

There will now be two documents with differing `_id`'s and all other fields identical in your database.

Does this clarify things a bit?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I ended up getting the `doc`, removing `_id` and saving :)

Comment: How did you remove the _id?

Comment: @JoeTidee You can use `delete doc._id` will remove the `_id` property from the `doc` object!

Comment: This does not answer the question unfortunately. To truly clone a document, you would do: `new Model(doc.toObject())`.

Comment: What are the approaches for copying the entire collection and create it with new name Through Mongoose? As I know how to clone/Copy the collection through cmd, But this things not work on mongoose. Any help is appreciated

Comment: sorry but this answer is bad, you just can do: var doc1= doc.toJSON(); var doc2= doc.toJSON(); and you have 2 objects with same data, no query.

Comment: Great answer but, this does not work as expected. You cannot delete an _id on a Mongoose object. Second, the id is created on the local object, so saving twice does not create two identical objects. It just saves the same document twice. Even if you create a new id. This might be a version thing as this answer is from 2013. Maybe it used to work.

Answer (score 92):

You need to reset `d1.isNew = true;` as in:

```
Model.findById(yourid).exec(
    function(err, doc) {
        doc._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        doc.isNew = true; //<--------------------IMPORTANT
        doc.save(callback);
    }
);
```

Comment: you could have commented on her answer or edited the answer !

Comment: This also does not work. Perhaps it's a version thing since this is 2014. Maybe it used to work.

Answer (score 11):

My two cents:

```js
const doc = await DocModel.findById(id);
let obj = doc.toObject();
delete obj._id;
const docClone = new DocModel(obj);
await docClone.save();
```

Comment: Isn't `exec` redundant here

Answer (score 3):

So, a lot of these answers will work well for simple docs, but there could be an error case when you're trying to make a deep clone of complex documents.

If you have arrays of subdocs, for example, you can end up with duplicate _ids in your copied document, which can cause subtle bugs later.

To do a deep clone of a mongoose doc, I suggest trying something like:

```js
//recursively remove _id fields
function cleanId(obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj))
        obj.forEach(cleanId);
    else {
        delete obj['_id'];
        for (let key in obj)
            if (typeof obj[key] == 'object')
                cleanId(obj[key]);
    }
}

let some_doc = await SomeModel.findOne({_id: some_id});
let new_doc_object = cleanId(some_doc.toObject());
let new_doc = new SomeModel(new_doc_object);
await new_doc.save();
```

This is going to be a pretty safe approach, and will ensure that every part of your object is cloned properly with newly generated _id fields on save.

Answer (score 2):

The following code to clone documents:

```
Model.findById(yourid).exec(
        function(err, doc) {
            var newdoc = new Model(doc);
            newdoc._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
            newdoc.save(callback);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

For simply clone use this :

```
Context.findOne({
    _id: context._id
})
    .then(function(c) {
        c._id = undefined;
        c.name = context.name;
        c.address = context.address;
        c.created = Date.now();
        return Context.create(c.toObject());
    }).then(function(c) {
        return res.json({
            success: true,
            context: context
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        next(err, req, res);
    });
```

Comment: This might be more simply stated as you just have to copy object properties. I've not found any of the approaches to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
const cloneDoc = (doc, model)=>{
  const copyDoc = new Model({
    ...doc.toObject(),
    _id: undefined,
  });
  copyDoc.isNew = true;
  return copyDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy a document into the same collection or different collection first get (query) the data and make a copy of the data. Afterwards remove the _id from the new list as you can't from the current data. This will allow you to insert a new record with new _id assigned from mongodb

change searchBy to what you are trying to find the document by.
change collectionA and collectionB to the name of the collection to create you copy to. Currently we are searching in collectionA and copying the data in collectionB

```
collectionA.find(searchBy).exec(function (err, doc) {
      // create a new copy
      let newDoc = { ...doc[0] }._doc;

      // delete property from new copy (remove _id).
      delete newDoc._id;

      // insert copy into db
      var newdoc = new collectionB(newDoc);
      newdoc.save();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can basically use .clone()  to get a copy.

```
const cars = Cars.find();
const carsCopy = cars.clone();

await cars;
await carsCopy;
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-clone

Comment: This example will clone the schema, not the document