# How to clone a mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is a followup to [Easiest way to copy/clone a mongoose document instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324843/easiest-way-to-copy-clone-a-mongoose-document-instance), which isn't working for me.

The following code throws a "cannot edit Mongo _id" field, rather than wiping the ._id and creating a new document in the collection.

Is there a better way to clone all values of a document into a new document, for further use/testing/etc?

I'm on Mongoose 3.8.12/Express 4.0, and I have also tested this on creating a new ObjectID in the 'undefined' s1._id field below.

```
router.route('/:sessionId/test/:testId')
    .post(function(req,res){        
        Session.findById(req.params.sessionId).exec(
        function(err, session) {
            var s1 = new Session();
                s1 = session;
                s1._id = undefined;

                console.log('posting new test', s1._id);      // your JSON
                s1.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json( 'new session ', req.body );
                });
         }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and proving the answer.  However you should add this as an answer yourself (and accept it) rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

```
var s1 = new Session(session);
s1._id = undefined;
```

Comment: You can't save a document without an _id, how can this even work? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345274/mongoose-data-saving-without-id

Comment: This method initialises empty arrays if you have defined any arrays in schema.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a new id for the document you want to clone and set [isNew](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) to true, so given "session" is the document you want to clone:

```
session._doc._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
session.isNew = true;
session.save(...);
```