# Mongoose data saving without _id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose with node.js application. I don't want _id field in record.
I am using this code to save my record without _id field. But it is giving error

> document must have an _id before saving

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PlayerSchema = new Schema({
    player_id :  { type: Number },
    player_name : { type: String },
    player_age  : { type: Number },
    player_country : { type: String }
}
, { _id: false }
);

var Player =  mongoose.model('Player', PlayerSchema );

        var athlete = new Player();
        athlete.player_id = 1;
        athlete.player_name = "Vicks";
        athlete.player_age  = 20;
        athlete.player_country = "UK";

        athlete.save(function(err) {
            if (err){
                console.log("Error saving in PlayerSchema"+ err);
            }
        });
```

I am using mongoose version 3.8.14

Comment: Do you really need to save data without _id, or you just don't want to declare it yourself?

Comment: i don't want to save _id in record. I am generating my own unique player_id.

Comment: you can define a unique index on the player_id field to ensure uniqueness, or you can rename your player_id to be _id. One way or another, a document must have an _id in mongoDB, you'll just be delegating its creation to the Database layer.  Have you tried skipping the ```{ _id: false }``` in the schema definition?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, You can not skip having a primary key for the document but you can override the primary key content, you can define your own primary key for each document.

Try the following schema for the same.

```
var PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id :  { type: Number },
player_name : { type: String },
player_age  : { type: Number },
player_country : { type: String },
```

}
);

I have replaced your `player_id` with `_id`. Now you have control over the primary key of the document and the system won't generate the key for you.

There are some plugins which can also do the `autoincremet` for your primary key. https://github.com/chevex-archived/mongoose-auto-increment. You might try these as well.

Also, about the error you are getting :
Any document is an object and should be wrapped inside the `curly brackets` you can not define two independent object in the same document. So you are getting this error.

Comment: This is auto generated by Mongo; overriding property _id of type mongoose.Types.ObjectId() with a Number will give you many errors in the future.

Comment: Can you please explain what type of errors we might be facing following this approach ?

Comment: @MinkeshJain key collisions, it's better to let database does it's job

Answer (score 3):

Copying an answer given on a similar [Github issue comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3638#issuecomment-334255443):

> The `_id` option exists to prevent one being created and assigned to
> every sub-document within your document.
>
> So, it's not for this:
>
> ```
> var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
> ThingSchema = new Schema({    
>    name: String,  
>    categories: [{         
>       label: {            
>          type: String,            
>          uppercase: true      
>       },      
>       value: String
>    }]
> }, {_id: false});
> //   ^^^^^^^^^
> // this won't work
> ```
>
> It's for this:
>
> ```
> var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
> ThingSchema = new Schema({
>     name: String,
>     categories: [{
>        label: {
>           type: String,
>           uppercase: true
>        },
>        value: String,
>        _id: false // <--- this works
>     }]
> });
> ```
>
> Took me a while but, after running into the same problem, I found the
> documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#option_id).

Answer (score 0):

instade of writing this

```
{
    player_id :  { type: Number },
    player_name : { type: String },
...}
```

write this:-

```
{
    _id :  { type: Number },
    _name : { type: String },
    _age  : { type: Number },
    _country : { type: String }
}
```

hence `_id` will be `players_id`

then further write code like this:-

```
var athlete = new Player();
        athlete._id = 1;
        athlete._name = "Vicks";
        athlete._age  = 20;
        athlete._country = "UK";

        athlete.save(function(err) {
            if (err){
                console.log("Error saving in PlayerSchema"+ err);
            }
        });
```