# Cant add model to the mongo database.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud

I am newbie to api creation. Iam trying to create an entry to the mongodb. The database connections are made promptly. I have written the below code for input of data into the mongo DB.

```
// Node Module dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Local Module dependencies
var common = require('./common.js');
//var request = require('request');

//common.autoIncrement.initialize(common.conn);

//---------------Schema Definitions---------------------//
var userSchema = common.Schema({

    _id: common.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user_name: String,
    gender: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['male', 'female'],
        default: 'male'
    },
    contact: Number,
    profile_pic: String,
    address: String,
    role: String,
    dob: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    collage_name: String,
    course: String,
    college_roll: String,
    specialization: String

});

var User = common.conn.model('User', userSchema);

router.route('/')
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);

        var item = new User(req.body);

        //========calling postModel method===============

        postUser(item, function (result) {

            res.send(result);
        });
   });
module.exports = router;
//========postModel method============//
function postUser(item, fn) {
    item.save(function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('user:', item);
        fn(item);
   })
}
```

But the thing is the database is not getting updated, i cannot find what the error is. This is the output i get while i try to put some data in to database using postman.

```
 db connection established to medicoshere database 
    { dob: '2016-08-21T02:37:11.969Z',
      gender: 'male',
      user_name: 'ria nivas' }
    Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in      your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
    [Error: document must have an _id before saving]
    user: { user_name: 'ria nivas',
      dob: Sun Aug 21 2016 08:07:11 GMT+0530 (IST),
      gender: 'male' }
    POST /register 200 67.420 ms - 74
```

but i see no contents are updated to my db.The first line of the output is logged using

```
app.db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('db connection established to medicoshere database ');
```

Is there anything else i need to do to update my database.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you don't need to declare _id in your model. If you add it, you should generate it by yourself. check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345274/mongoose-data-saving-without-id

Comment: Thanks it worked..... I have one more question .... How to avoid this warning...                                                                                            Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: You could use the way what @Aron mention. `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting the `Mongoose: mpromise` etc error I assume you are using a recent version of NodeJS, which means you can use ES2015 native Promises. Therefore to get rid of the MongoDB Promises error you can simply replace Mongo's promises with the native ones.

To do this put the following line of code somewhere between your `require('mongoose')` and `mongoose.connect(MongoURI)`:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

This simply reassigns the built in Mongo Promises library with native promises and should get rid of your error.