# How to duplicate a document using Mongoose JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Model.findById(req.body.myid, function (err, results) {
      var doc = new Model(results);
      doc._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
      doc.serial = req.body.serial;
      doc.remarks = req.body.remarks;
      doc.save(function(err) {
        if(err){
          res.json({ success: false });
        }else {
          res.json({ success: true });
        }
      });
    });
```

> How can i create copy of a document and save using mongoosejs ??

Comment: why this doesn't work? what is the error? try maybe to do `results.toObject()`

Comment: Please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324843/easiest-way-to-copy-clone-a-mongoose-document-instance

Comment: `code` (node:8260) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
{ Error
    at model.wrappedPointCut [as save] 
  message: 'No matching document found for id,
  name: 'VersionError' } `code`

Comment: `code` doc.isNew = true;`code`

Comment: Thankyou Tom & Pter.... worked!

Answer (score 1):

Also need to set `isNew` to `true`

```js
doc._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
doc.serial = req.body.serial;
doc.remarks = req.body.remarks;
doc.isNew = true;
```